# Expo Go backgroundimage shows up on web view but not mobile device when connected via usb

Tags: android, react-native

`source={{ URI:'/Images/sql.png'}}` 
The background image for this code only shows up on web view but when I include the https link on uri it work on phone and web view.

Things I done so far. I installed ruby on rails and add the bundle bat file to environment variables. I saw another article about this topic that said use the command prompt to make the background image work on the mobile device.

They said to use the command prompt react-native bundle --platform android --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --dev false --reset-cache --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/ but I keep getting unknown command bundle but when I use bundle -v I get the version. Its either the way I got my code set up on the URI or I need some special command prompt.

Comment: you need to add expo-asset https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/asset/

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use external images you can use "require" for local images;

```
require("/Images/sql.png");
```

for web view and mobile.

```
source={require("/Images/sql.png")}
```

Comment: That only work for type script files I'm using a JavaScript file.

Comment: This is javascript. Did you use it or not? @WanWan

Comment: Thank you guys. I don't know why it was bugging out but after restarting my computer it works now. I just had to change the paths a couple of time until it was able to read using the require code.

Comment: I'm happy to hear you fixed it.